# MySQL create index ...performance issues

Tags: php, mysql, performance, indexing

I have a table - ok well three tables artists, venues and events..about 150k events. What I am looking to understand mysql create index more clearly as it relates to my specific problem. That problem is basically it taking very long for the php software to load a page that is pulling this data....WAY too long.  And I have absolutely no time for cleaning up code...only for optimizing mysql, memcache maybe?, adding more ram etc. All data is text by the way...

Any and all thoughts are welcome!

Thank you~

Comment: Do you know what query is taking too long to finish?

Comment: Can you show the `CREATE TABLE` syntax of the tables involved?

Comment: What is your specific question? What is taking long? How does your question relate to `CREATE INDEX`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the MySQL [slow query log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/slow-query-log.html) to identify which query(ies) are causing the delay, then run [EXPLAIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html) on them to see which (if any) indexes are being used.  If you see that indexes are not being used, consider adding indexes to relevant columns.  Such columns would be those used in WHERE and JOIN clauses.  For example, if you are joining `venues` to `events` on `venue_id` you may want to index `events`.`venue_id` to improve JOIN performance.

For example:

```
CREATE INDEX event_venue_id ON events (venue_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you want to create an index on the fields that will most commonly be used for searching records in the table. [CREATE INDEX documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html)

To understand your problem more clearly, you need to identify the main queries you believe are performing too slowly and run an [EXPLAIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html) query on that. That output will help you understand which columns should be indexed to improve performance in your application.